# Evolution of perfective aspect from Sanskrit derivational suffix -ka in Modern Indo-Aryan languages

Tags: historical-linguistics, morphosyntax, sanskrit, aspect, indo-aryan

It is well attested that the Sanskrit derivational suffix -ka for adjectives together with the syntesized participle on nominals like krta-ka>done, evolved as the possessive case marker in modern Indo-Aryan. My question is, is it possible that the -ka (apart from being possessive case marker) has extended its function as perfective aspect in any modern Indo-Aryan languages? If yes, how do I determine the stages of its evolution as perfective aspect? What should I read?

Comment: Can you please edit/elaborate on -> _like krta-ka>done_

Comment: Sanskrit root kr 'do' followed by the perfective participle form -ta means 'done', and by adding the derivational suffix for forming adjectives -ka  it means the same 'done' only krtaka is an expanded variation of krta

Answer (score 1):

Your presuppositions are faulty. Sanskrit *kṛtaka* is exactly what it is: a past passive participle from *kṛ* 'to do', followed by the adjectival suffix -*ka*. As such, it means 'the one who has been done'. Then, depending on the context, you can translate it in a [number of ways](http://sanskritdictionary.com/k%E1%B9%9Btaka/61041/1), including a simple 'done', but this does not make it an "expanded variation of *kṛta*". It's another lexeme, not just a word-form of *kṛ*. Therefore, you can't search in the Modern Indo-Aryan languages for a continuation of something that did not exist in the Old Indo-Aryan.